# How can I make the index count from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: java

I was trying out the JetBrains course of Java Core.
This is the exercise:

> Let's implement the simplest search engine possible ever. It should search for a specific word in a multi-word input line. The input line contains several words separated by a space. The words are numbered according to their order, with the first word having index 1. Consider that all the words in the line are unique, so there can be no repetition. Write a simple program that reads two lines: a line of words and a line containing the search word. The program must search in the first line for a word specified in the second one. The program should output the index of the specified word. If there is no such word in the first line, the program should print Not Found. Please remember that indexes start from 1!
> You should output exactly one line.
> The lines that start with > represent the user input. Note that these symbols are not part of the input.

Example 1:

"> first second third fourth"
"> third"
"3"

Example 2:

"> cat dog and mouse"
"> elephant"
"Not found"

This is my code:

```
package search;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sc1 = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] splited = sc1.split("\\s+");

        String sc2 = scanner.nextLine();
        int index = 0;
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i <= splited.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sc2.contains(splited[i])) {
                flag = true;
                index = i+1; //line updated, same result
            }
        }
        
        if (flag) {
           System.out.println(index);
            }
        else {
           System.out.println("not found ");
        }
    }            
}
```

And this is the answer:

Wrong answer in test #1

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

"---"

"> hello my name is alex"

"> my"

"1"

Update: Thanks a lot for your comments @shriakhilc and @Gardener. I updated the code, as per Gardener's advice, and now it gives me this example:

> what a beautiful place
> what
> 2

What could I do to make it count from 1? (I also tried changing the initial values of both i and index separately and doesn't work either, also modified length but nothing either.)

Comment: Based on example 1, it expects your output to be 1-indexed, so "my" should be 2.

Comment: Probably want `index = (i + 1);` to conform with the required indexing.  You also may not want `contains` but it would work for your examples.  Your code would show 3 for "me" (assuming the previous fix).

Comment: since arrays in Java are indexed starting from `0` it is more adequate to leave the code starting at `0` and just change the output so that instead of `0` it prints `1`; instead of `1` it prints `2`, ...

Comment: It was equals instead of contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make array indexes start at 1 in Java, you will have to adjust the result.

I spotted several issues in your code, but none is related to your problem:

1. You should replace the condition of your loop `i <= splited.length - 1` with the simpler `i < splited.length`
2. Rename `flag` to `found` as this is what the flag means.
3. You should extend your loop end condition with `flag` so you stop searching after the first "hit": `(i < splited.length) && !found`

Now for your actual problem: I would suggest that you simply store the value of `i` into `index` and do the calculation only at the output, so inside the if in the loop just set `index = i;` and add `1` just on the output: `System.out.println(index + 1);`

Make sure that with all your attempts to fix the code, you add the 1 only once to index, your update sounds as if you applied the fix twice.

**Update**
Also trim your input string to prevent empty array elements at the beginning of the splitted array:
`String[] splited = sc1.trim().split("\\s+");`

Comment: Ok, with the help of a friend, using equals instead of contains actually worked. But anyways, thanks for your answer. I'll optimize the code for myself. Also, I did try out at one point, to add 1 to index out of loop but it wouldn't work either. Thanks once more.